# Setting shadow color for the title of UIButton in the nib

Tags: colors, uibutton, title, nib, shadow

I am developing a simple iPhone application. I want to set the shadow color for the title of a UIButton in the nib.

Can someone help me in finding the set shadow color for the title in the nib?

Thanks and Regards,
Deepa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in the Interface Builder you have to select the UIButton and open the inspector. Then you'll see the different properties of the UIButton. There are two properties called Shadow, the first one is to set the Shadow Color, the other one is to set the Offset of the Shadow. Try aout like you wanna have it, you'll se the changes immediately.

That's all, pretty simple.